# Calling PySWIP inside a Flask endpoint crashes the app

Tags: python, flask, swi-prolog

I'm setting up a Flask + SWI Prolog project using PySWIP and I need to call `prolog.asserta`
when a certain endpoint is queried. The problem is that when `@route('/test'...` is called, the app crashes without further explanation .

The code that I currently have is the following:

```py
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def addToKnowledgeBase():
    prolog.asserta("test(foo)")

    query = "test(X)"
    for result in  prolog.query(query):
        path = result["X"]
        print(path)
    .
    .
    .
```

Every other endpoint works well, but this ones closes the API.

The only error message outputting is in the browser `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

And I don't know if this helps, but terminal says `Process returned 245`